# $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous , has a finite number of local maxima and minima ; then how to prove that $f$ is bounded variation on $[a,b]$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, bounded-variation

If $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function having  finite number of local maxima and minima ; then how to prove that $f$ is bounded variation on $[a,b]$ ?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Every monotonic function on a closed interval is of bounded variation.  Split your function into finitely many monotonic segments.

Comment: Please give some more details ; how to get those monotone functions ?

Comment: In between a min and a max, the function must be increasing.  In between a max and a min, the function must be decreasing.

Comment: How to show that in between a local max and min , the function must be decreasing ? And is it certain that min's and max's occur alternatively ?